# Remove branding from custom kernel

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I have an assignment to build a custom kernel which removes all the drivers/plugins that are not needed and also remove any traces that it is Ubuntu's.

Basically, my teacher wants us to strip it down to the bare-bones where we can still install/add plugins if needed afterwards.

I followed [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) tutorial to build; however, when I got to "Testing the new kernel" and restarted, everything remained the same. It booted back up to Ubuntu (menu never showed up to pick kernel). The size of the OS went up by 20gb as well. I checked the kernel version with `uname -r` both times to make sure.

Please help me remove the "bloatware" and remove the branding.

Comment: Please clarify exactly which "branding" and "bloatware" you want to remove.

Comment: Branding meaning removing any thing that says Ubuntu from the OS. For example, when installing the distro you clearly know it's Ubuntu. Professor wants us to make it seem like it isn't.

By bloatware, disabling anything from menuconfig that is not needed for the hardware I have. And of course, programs like office, games, etc...

Comment: Apparently you are confusing kernel messages and OS messages. The kernel itself should identify itself as an Ubuntu kernel only in the version string, if at all.

Comment: Oh I see. I pulled up the example he gave us. He said he used Ubuntu to make the kernel. You would never be able to tell though. It looks nothing like Ubuntu. Either way, how can I proceed? The link I mentioned didn't really help me.

Comment: Are you personally using Ubuntu?  If so, what version?

Answer (score -1):

forget starting with a distro, compile from source and go headless (i.e. text mode) gui's are not going to help become learned.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Compilation/Traditional

yes, Arch is a distro, but it's showing you how to do it, without telling you to go Slackware.

have fun, learning is the best lunch to have!

Comment: Advising an inexperienced user to use the kernel.org source is terrible advice since they lack all the bug fixes carried by distributions.

Comment: Thank you, but my professor wants us to use Ubuntu. I'll definitely do it this way on my free time but not for this assignment.